# How do I insert integral with stacked limits in an ms word equation by shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

How do I insert integral **with stacked limits** in an ms word equation by shortcut?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably best to record a macro for this. Use the `Developer` tab, record your actions, then save it with a hotkey.